# Email doesn't send based on variable name

Tags: php

My email will only send if I type in the actual address rather than using $usr_email, although it says 'message sent'. The Email address comes from the user_email field in users table.
This is defined with 
    $id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);

```
if (isset($_POST['doSend'])) {


function getTwo($query){
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$res) {
        trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        return $row[0];
    }
}

$getuserinfo_q = "SELECT user_email AND user_name FROM users WHERE 
id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";

$getuserinfo_e=mysql_query($getuserinfo_q);

if(mysql_num_rows($getuserinfo_e) < 1){

    echo "User details not found - User_id is not in DB";

    exit();

}

$user_info_val=mysql_fetch_assoc($getuserinfo_e);

if(empty($user_info_val['user_email'])){

    echo "there is no such column name as 'user_email'"; //tell the user about column

    exit(); //shut off the script

}


$usr_email=$user_info_val['user_email'];
  $user_name=$user_info_val['user_name'];



$sqltest = "SELECT completed_status From users where id =
'$_SESSION[user_id]'";
$isSending = getTwo($sqltest);
$isSending === false;
if($isSending >= 6){
    require_once "Mail.php";
    require_once "Mail.php";



    $from = "<xxx>";
    $to = "$usr_email";
    $subject = "hi";
$body ="Chi ";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxxx";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } else {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
}
else
    header ("Location: error.php");



}
```

Comment: You know that this is the badest thing you can do with mysql? select count(*) as total from users where user_email='$usr_email' OR user_name='$user_name'. Little hint: sql injection

Comment: have you tried echoing `$data['usr_email'];`?

Comment: and you're also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: It just gives undefined index usr_email when trying to echo.

Comment: still the same messages when i change

Comment: That means there isn't a "usr_email" key in your $_POST. Try `print($_POST);` Tell me what you see.

Comment: it means you have no `$data['usr_email'];` defined.

Comment: but surely that line is defining it and the above line defines data?@webbandit

Comment: @user1296762 Sorry, my mistake. Try `print_r($_POST);` and tell me what you see with that.

Comment: Array ( [doSend] => Submit Application )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIG EDIT:

OKAY, So lets hope this works -_-

```
$getuserinfo_q = "SELECT user_email AND user_name FROM users WHERE id ='
".intval($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";

$getuserinfo_e=mysql_query($getuserinfo_q);

if(mysql_numb_rows($getuserinfo_e) < 1){

echo "User details not found - User_id is not in DB";

exit();

}

$user_info_val=mysql_fetch_assoc($getuserinfo_e);

if(empty($user_info_val['user_email'])){

echo "there is no such column name as 'user_email'"; //tell the user about column

exit(); //shut off the script

}


$usr_email=$user_info_val['user_email'];


$sqltest = "SELECT completed_status FROM users WHERE id ='
".intval($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";
$isSending = getTwo($sqltest);
$isSending === false;
if($isSending >= 6){
    require_once "Mail.php";

// Start NEW CLASS (for your weird Mail function)

$m_class=new Mail;


    $from = "<xxx>";
    $to = "$usr_email";
    $subject = "hi";
$body ="Chi ";

$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxxx";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject);


$smtp = $m_class->factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$mail = $m_class->send($to, $headers, $body);

}
else
    header ("Location: error.php");
```

As you may have noticed, I removed the error checking ( the `PEER::isError()` thing) simply because I could not get my head around how that function should be called (not statically). But, other than that, the code above should do the trick (hopefully).

Give it a go, and let me know how it works.

Comment: the only code I have is what I have posted. there is no other `$_POST` data in there so maybe I can delete this?

Comment: Right, well there is your problem. How do you expect `$_POST` to have any data related to "usr_email" without you putting it there?

Comment: yes I know but when just using  `$usr_email = 'usr_email';` the email is never received

Comment: In your foreach loop you have `$key` - is that supposed to be the key of the arrays? and `$value` is supposed to be the value of that array key?

Comment: And thats because you're defining $usr_email again (in your foreach loop). Comment/remove this line out: `$usr_email = $data['usr_email'];` and set `$usr_email` to your own email, and you should receive it just fine.

Comment: yes but the foreach loop was a second attempt as the first attempt the email was never received

Comment: So, how do you/your user input their email (so that it goes into `$_POST`)

Comment: yes I receive it, but I want $email to = user_email in my users table `where user_id = ".intval($_SESSION['user_id']);`

Comment: they input their email from a register page which then goes to the user table so I need to pull it back out

Comment: And do you do this `SELECT` query in your code? If you do, post it on your question so i can have a look.

Comment: so you only want to send this email to one user, which has just registered to your site/app by using the user_id in $_SESSION to grab the email address from the table? if so, why the foreach loop?

Comment: yes the user that is logged in. I've deleted that after changing the $user_email line but still not working

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts but it is saying undefined_index with this line  `$usr_email=$user_info_val['user_email'];`

Comment: put this at the top of your code: `error_reporting(-1);` Tell me what you get.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: user_email in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\myaccount.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\myaccount.php on line 37

Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\myaccount.php on line 75

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Mail\smtp.php on line 365` and a lot more similar to that

Comment: Right, so you are re-defining the vars in another file (myaccount.php). Post the contents of that file in an edit. Also, that tells me `user_email` is undefined, not `usr_email`....So this issues lies in another one of your files (again, myaccount.php).

Comment: the page I have pasted and working on now is myaccount.php. it refers to the user_email that is in single quotes

Comment: I've edited the code again. Replace all of your code with that, and let me know what you get. Also, if myaccount.php is the script you're working with, why is it complaining about `user_name` when I haven't even mentioned that in the code above. Do you have code there that you're not showing me?

Comment: using ur code I get here is no such column name as 'user_email' but there definitely is!!

Comment: Right, do a `print_r($user_info_val);` and post the result.

Comment: also, replace the line this code is on, with this: `$getuserinfo_q = "SELECT user_email and user_name FROM users WHERE id ='
".intval($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";`

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: user_info_val in

Comment: did you put `print_r($user_info_val);` at the end of the script, or at the beginning? Put it at the end, and let me know of the result.

Comment: Yes I've put it after the line where it is defined and still saying the same

Comment: and there is no such column name as 'user_email'

Comment: This is really weird. Try `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($getuserinfo_e));`

Comment: Array ( [user_email and user_name] => 0 ) there is no such column name as 'user_email'

Comment: Right, change your query to this: `$getuserinfo_q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='
".intval($_SESSION['user_id'])."'";`, but keep the `print_r()`.

Comment: this displays all the info in the row for my user

Comment: right, your query was the problem. This was because you had `SELECT user_email and user_name` which has `and` (in non capital). It should be `AND`. do you receive the email now?

Comment: It says message sent but still not received it

Comment: From the responce you recieved earlier, when turning on error reporting, I see there was `Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\euisample\myaccount.php on line 75` because you are calling a function that is not defined statically. You also do the same with `PEAR::isError()`. I have noticed you have taken this code from the web - Which has a few errors in it. Check My FULL EDIT.

Comment: The pear:iseeror() works fine on another of my pages. I really don't understand why this is not working, now says:User details not found - User_id is not in DB

Comment: are you sure your `$_SESSION['user_id']` is set?

Comment: I've put this in `'$_SESSION['user_id'] = 'id';`but still no luck. my id column in the table is called 'id' not `user_id`. this doesnt make a difference does it?

Comment: Thats Odd. Well lets have a look at the end query then. Put this echo statement inside the `mysql_numb_rows` `IF` statement: `echo ."<br><br>".$getuserinfo_q;`

Comment: it is meant to be num_rows isn't it?

Comment: No. There is an if statement:(`f(mysql_numb_rows($getuserinfo_e) < 1){
echo "User details not found - User_id is not in DB";
exit();}`) You need to put that echo statement inside of it. SO: `f(mysql_numb_rows($getuserinfo_e) < 1){ echo ."<br><br>".$getuserinfo_q;
echo "User details not found - User_id is not in DB";
exit();
}` Replace the old if statement with that...

Comment: yes it is something to do with the session `SELECT user_email AND user_name FROM users WHERE id =' 0'User details not found - User_id is not in DB` I tried start_session but it said a session was already running

Comment: There is your problem then. Your session is "0". How are you defining the session?

Comment: if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))

Comment: take it out of an if statement and set it either way, just to be sure: `$_SESSION['user_id']="my ID";`

Comment: nope the user is still '0'. I will just have to take this aspect out of my system. thanks anyway

Comment: try removing `intval($_SESSION['user_id'])` in the query and replace it with just `$_SESSION['user_id']`

Comment: there is no such column name as 'user_email'

Comment: and does the query still return "0" as the session? Why don't you re-post your new code in your question so I can take a look. We've gotten this deep into it, I don't really want to give up. ;)

Comment: the session is correct now but still saying no column of user_email
so wierd

Comment: Okay, do a `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($getuserinfo_e));` above the `mysql_numb_rows` `IF` statement. Let me know of the result.

Comment: I just checked your edit. Your query is wrong. it should be: `$getuserinfo_q = "SELECT user_email AND user_name FROM users WHERE 
id='".$_SESSION[user_id]."'";`

Comment: I had to put single quotes around the user_id but still says no such column name

Comment: that statment produces: Array ( [user_email AND user_name] => 0 )

Comment: In the query, replace the `AND` with a `,` so it should be `SELECT user_email,user_name` instead of `SELECT user_email AND user_name`. Tell me what you get with the `print_r` then.

Comment: it gives the actual email and username in the print_r yet still says no column user_email!

Comment: it shows like this `there is no such column name as 'user_email'` Im wondering if it in single quotes somehwere it shouldn't be but it is nowhere in the code

Comment: Put this above the if statement: `echo "<br><br>I found ".mysql_numb_rows($getuserinfo_e)." rows in the DB <br>";`

Comment: I found 1 rows in the DB 
there is no such column name as 'user_email'

Comment: Right, well that does not make sense -_- BUT - remove that `if` statement from your code completely. (this one: `if(mysql_numb_rows($getuserinfo_e) < 1){

echo "User details not found - User_id is not in DB";

exit();

}`) This must have been a mistake on my side. My bad. That should do the trick now.